# How do I get the estimator and optimization method of a lavaan model as a variable?

Tags: r, r-lavaan

I have some data to which I have fitted a model in lavaan

```
fit <- sem(model, full_data)
```

The summary (`summary(fit)`) shows the used solver (optimization method as well as estimator), but I can't figure out how to extract that information and store it into a variable; I can only manage to print it as part of the summary. How can I access these two values and store them in a variable?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `str(fit)` you can see the structure of `fit` and all the informations which are saved in the object. In lavaan it is a lot of information, so it is not so easy to find, but in your case you can find your informations in `Options`, so

```
fit@Options$optim.method
fit@Options$estimator
```

should give you the information you need and you can store them in a variable.